# How to change Windows 10 brightness slider back to button after 19h1 update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, brightness

The Windows 10 19H1 update changed the brightness button in the action center to a slider. I hate it and and want the button back - how do i do that?

Comment: Downgrade back to an earlier version of Windows 10, or find an application that does what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the update because it has resolved my extensive 100% disk usage - I will just have to get used to sliding that stupid slider all the time